# NullPointerException in IabHelper onServiceConnected callback

Tags: android, google-play-services, in-app-billing

When calling IabHelper#startSetup I am seeing a crash with exception

```
05-08 14:01:35.448    5815-5815/com.test.test /AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.test.test, PID: 5815
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.test.android.lib.iab.util.IabHelper$1.onServiceConnected(IabHelper.java:247)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1110)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1127)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Lately I have noticed Play Services crashing on all my devices and it seems like this issue is related to this. Restarting the device fixing this issue. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

The service gets instantiated by IabHelper when IabHelper#startSetup is called

```
 billingHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                    subscriber.onNext(result);
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }
            });
```

You can see the IabHelper file here https://gist.github.com/darussian/bf28c44970dc308f35b6#file-gistfile1-java-L247

Comment: Could you post the code where you are calling the doConnected() method?

Comment: @TimKranen The Iab library handles starting this service. I posted the code used to initiate this process.

Comment: please identify IabHelper line 247

Comment: https://gist.github.com/darussian/bf28c44970dc308f35b6#file-gistfile1-java-L247

Comment: Looks like the service IabHelper is trying to connect to is null.  Have you uploaded your apk to google play beta channel?   Does the device/emulator have google play services installed?

Comment: The app is live, the device has google play services installed. Past couple months Google Play services has been crashing across all my devices and it seems after this happens I run into this issue.

Comment: Might be helpful to list those device models and to see if Google Play Services is even reachable before attempting to use IABHelper. Its possible that those devices have google play services disabled via  Application Settings.